# W8BEN of Indian individual

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, withdrawal, form-w-8-ben

I need help in filling W8BEN form. I will use this to reduce (or zero) my 401K withholding (whenever I withdraw money) as there is a treaty between India & US.

I am not sure what should I fill in point 10.

I only have 401k money.

[W8BEN Form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf)

[Instructions to fill W8BEN](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw8ben.pdf)

[Point 10 from W8BEN form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyiNi.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only withdrawing from your 401(k), I believe you can leave it blank.

> Line 10 must be used only if you are claiming treaty benefits that require that you meet conditions not covered by the representations you make on line 9 and Part III. For example, persons claiming treaty benefits on royalties must complete this line if the treaty contains different withholding rates for different types of royalties.